# NPM run watch exit status 3221226505

Tags: npm, laravel-mix, npm-scripts

On my desktop when I run `npm run watch` everythign works as expected. However I'm setting up a new laptop and running into issues. I git pulled the latest version of what I'm working on to my laptop and ran npm install and then `npm run watch` and I get this error.

```
npm ERR! Exit status 3221226505
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the codefor.ca@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eslte\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-25T17_03_06_441Z-debug.log
```

I looked at the full log but I didn't see anything that explained the error to me.

Here's my package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  }
```

**recap**

- Works on desktop
- fails on laptop
- script is exactly the same on both

and the full log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~prewatch: codefor.ca@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: codefor.ca@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\sites\code-for-canada\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\eslte\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\DDEV;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\eslte\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\eslte\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\eslte\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: CWD: C:\sites\code-for-canada
10 silly lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: Returned: code: 3221226505  signal: null
12 info lifecycle codefor.ca@1.0.0~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: codefor.ca@1.0.0 watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221226505
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
14 verbose pkgid codefor.ca@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\sites\code-for-canada
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v11.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221226505
22 error codefor.ca@1.0.0 watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 3221226505
23 error Failed at the codefor.ca@1.0.0 watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221226505, true ]
```

Please advise

Answer (score 3):

This is crazy old, but I just had the same error (thanks Google). Adding this in case it helps anyone.

My issue was that I was running the wrong version of node.
`nvm list` shows which versions you have, and which you're currently using.
`nvm use 16` will switch to node 16.0.0 (or whatever).

I had been trying on node 14, this switch made all the things work!